# Extract an enhancement from one weapon and apply it to another

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

After completing the "the padawan exposed" mission with my sith juggernaut character, I have to choose between two rewards, one of them is called ["dread sith savage lightsaber"](http://www.torhead.com/item/cgysuPw/dread-sith-savage-lightsaber), in orange text.

I am tempted to choose this reward because it offers the following benefits over my purple  ["vindicator's lightsaber"](http://www.torhead.com/item/9ZxSN85/vindicators-lightsaber):

+51 Max Damage
+31 Min Damage
+8 Strength
-4 Endurance
+68 Power
+25 Force Power
-10 Defence Rating

The higher modification on my "vindicator's lightsaber" is the "enhancement" modification which is 72 as opposed to 70 on the other weapon.

I am going to choose the "dread sith savage lightsaber" because I think it will do more damage, is it possible to extract the benefits of this weapon and apply them to my previous weapon, whilst retaining the benefits of that weapon? Or can I take the enhancement from my previous weapon and add it to my new one? After double checking it seems that my new weapon has much better stats, but the enhancement is lower, so I would want to take the enchancement from my previous weapon and apply it to my new weapon.

What difference does it make if one is purple text and the other orange, which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weapon and gear shells have no intrisic stats whatsoever.  The amount of Force Power (or Tech Power) and Min/Max Damage is determined by the level of the Armoring/Hilt/Barrel, and so is the Armor Rating (in conjunction with the weight of the gear shell — Light, Medium, or Heavy).  All other stats are the sum of the stats on the modifications inside the shell.

So this means that, as a Juggernaut with Heavy armor, all Heavy or Adaptable gear shells work exactly the same given the same modifications.  Likewise, all Lightsabers, Focii, and Shields work exactly the same given the same modifications.

Moddable Purple and Orange shells function exactly the same way.  There are some Purple shells that are not moddable (mostly level 50 and lower Belts and Bracers), though.

And yes, you can absolutely mix and match modifications from multiple pieces and stick them into one.  You should turn on Show Detailed Item Tooltips (`Preferences -> User Interface -> Tooltip`) so that you can easily see the stat breakdown of each piece.  Look at the count of stats on each modification, rather than the Rating; the Rating is only a rough guide and quite frequently there will be 70 mods with more or better stats than 72 mods, and so on.